# Automatically move to the next column each time it is run

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have been able to build a preliminary web scraper using VBA, but my problem is that it will only paste the contents in specific areas/cells that I have selected in Excel. I would like to run this code daily, and each time it runs, have it paste the contents into the next column in Excel (next column should be empty). I am relatively new to VBA and programming in general, just as a disclaimer! Also, I can't use any other software/programming language for the web scraper.

Code snippet:

```
Set doc = appIE.Document
Set rowdata= doc.getElementByID("")

If Not rowdata Is Nothing Then
Set clip = New DataObject
clip.SetText "" & row data.outerHTML & ""
End If

clip.PutInClipboard
Sheet1.Select
Sheet1.Range("A9").Select
Sheet1.PasteSpecial "Unicode Text"


Range("A9:B12").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Range("A9").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
Range ("B10").Select
```

Answer (score 0):

In Excel you can use relative references.

For example, the next code will move one column & paste the word "Complete" each time I run it:

```
Sub Test()

Dim iCol As Long, iRow As Long

'For the example, I'm fixing row 5, but you can iterate them as well
iRow = 5

'I'm counting how many cells are full in row 5
iCol = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rows(5)) + 1

'I'll use previously defined references to populate the newest cell each time I run the macro
Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = "Complete"

End Sub
```

Trying to adapt it to your code, it would be:

```
Sub ScraperVBA()

Dim WSh As Worksheet, Rng1 As Range
Dim iCol As Long, iRow As Long, iRowT As Long

Set Doc = appIE.Document
Set RowData = Doc.getElementByID("")

If Not RowData Is Nothing Then
    Set Clip = New DataObject
    Clip.SetText "" & RowData.outerHTML & ""
End If

Set WSh = Sheet1
    Clip.PutInClipboard
    'Setting Row & Column identifiers
        iRow = 9
        iCol = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rows(iRow)) + 1
        Set Rng1 = WSh.Cells(iRow, iCol)
    'Sheet1.Select - This is not needed
    'Sheet1.Range("A9").Select - This is not needed

    Rng1.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    ' I don't understand what this section is for, but I'll dismiss it...
    'Range("A9:B12").Select
    'Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    'Range("A9").Select
    'ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
    'Range("B10").Select

End Sub
```

I hope that helps...

Comment: thanks for the response. I'm getting some errors, though, when trying the code. I was originally getting error 13 "type mismatch". I think that's cause for the page I'm getting info from, I'm not sure what the data/value types are (not just numbers, some text and weird formatting in the table). I tried to change some of the code to avoid this, deleting the Dim parts above, and just using iCol = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rows(1)) + 1 and having range as Sheet1.Range (1, iCol).Select but I'm getting error 1004, "Application-defined error". Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: § Hi, you should not delete the Dim declarations: they are basically stating that you are using an Excel sheet, a range, an numbers. § "Range" needs to be based on cells, in the form "Range({from cell}, {to cell})", for example Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(5, 3)) would be referring to A1:C5 in your spreadsheet. § With "iCol" I'm only getting the column number, so I can use "Cell" to refer to the actual cell using both Row Number & Column Number as identifiers.

Comment: § Btw, a way to identify errors easily in Excel VBA is to run the code you've adapted with key F8 ("debugging"). It will run it step by step & it will indicate you when the code is unable to continue.